# Are "How to convert <format> into <latex>" ok questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I wasn't sure about this question over [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/771/how-can-i-efficiently-convert-tei-documents-into-latex/796#796).

It was about TEI xml markup of books and the question was how to automatically process it to latex.

Are questions about processing docbook, texinfo, sphinx and other xml stuff into latex, fine here?

Are we more about *hand-written* latex and advanced knowledge of LaTeX?

Or questions "I have $x generate beautiful LaTeX processed pdf NOW!" are fine?

Comment: I planned to ask about options for TeX2wiki or "TeX on Drupal" but as a recent newbie who already had one question described as inappropriate, I am now hesitant to post them and first came here to find out where the limits actually are. Discussions like this one are helpful to get a feeling for the community.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, I think they're ok; I don't see why not. There are only finitely many such questions, and when we've answered all the corresponding questions for the popular formats, we'll be done. (Perhaps I'm too optimistic, though.)

Comment: I'm inclined to agree.  I think that the finite number of such together with the hassle in saying "Don't want this here" together with the slightly negative feeling that that gives means that it's not worth trying to ban these.  If we get flooded by them, we could revisit the issue.

Answer (score 4):

These seem like perfectly cromulent questions to me.  We'll never *really* be done with them, though, since new versions of M$ Office, OpenOffice, etc. will keep coming out, conversion software will get updated, people will try new ways of mixing TeX with webpages, and so forth.

Comment: Well, one reasonable answer for most such questions is something like "copy and paste the text into your text editor, then start adding the appropriate LaTeX markup". That kind of answer will presumably never become entirely obsolete, and if it did, that would be a happy day indeed!